# How can I make gnome shell default?

Tags: 10.10, gnome

How can I make gnome shell the default interface once it is installed? Upon login or to get it to show up as a session at the login screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

install the package `gnome3-session` on maverick to add a gdm entry to the login screen. you will then be able to choose whether you want gnome-shell or vanilla gnome.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome3-session
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to navigate to system>preferences>startup applications and add gnome-shell --replace

While not ideal or official, it will save time from running the command from the terminal or alt+f2 by executing it for you upon startup

Comment: This is just what I have been doing meanwhile, the above answer seems to be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

From the login screen select "GNOME Shell" from the session drop down. You can select it there just like you can select Unity, or KDE, or any other desktop environment you have installed.

Comment: this does not make it default